# Decision tree in Mathematica

Tags: machine-learning

I have data like these:

```
   (Age, Lot of Junk Food, Exercise, Status)
   (<30, Yes, Null, Unfit)
   (<30, No, Null, Fit)
   (>30, Null, No, Unfit)
   (>30, Null, Yes, Unfit)
```

that can be represented as a (decision) tree:

[image: Decision Tree]

How can I do these things in Mathematica?

Comment: Search "TreeGraph".

Comment: So for people `age>30` it does not matter what they eat :-D

Comment: I'm really sorry: I asked my question in a misleading way.

Comment: I thank all the people who tried to help me.
My question is not about the graphical representation of a tree.
I try to give a better explanation.
I have N "cases" (with N possibly very large) where each "case" establishes a correlation among M attributes
attribute1, attribute2, ..., attributeM
and some predictable outcome.
I want to build a model  whose main usage is to accept in input a new "case" and make a prediction (with some level of confidence, represented by a "lift chart") from it. Someone calls this model a "Decision Tree", someone calls it "Classification".

Answer (score 10):

```
edgeLabels = {"YES", "NO"};

leaves = AssociationThread[edgeLabels, {"Fit", "Unfit"}];
```

#### [`Tree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tree.html)

```
Tree["Age > 30", 
 AssociationThread[edgeLabels,
  {Tree["Exercise", leaves], 
   Tree["Lot of Junk Food", 
    ReplaceAll[{"Fit" -> "Unfit", "Unfit" -> "Fit"}]@leaves]}]]
```

[image]

#### [`RulesTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RulesTree.html)

```
rules = "Age > 30" ->
  <|"YES" -> "Exercise" -> <|"YES" -> "Fit", "NO" -> "Unfit"|>, 
   "NO" -> "Lot of Junk Food" -> <|"YES" -> "Unfit", "NO" -> "Fit"|>|>

RulesTree @ rules
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can display it like a binary tree where every vertex has a left and a right branch.

```
TreeForm[
 "Age > 30"["Lot of Junk Food"["Fit", "Unfit"]
  , "Exercise"["UnFit", "Fit"]]
 , DirectedEdges -> True
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , VertexLabeling -> True
 , VertexLabeling -> {1 -> "True"}
 (*,Frame \[Rule] True*)
 , Epilog -> {
   Text[Style["No", 14, Bold], {0.75, 1.25}], 
   Text[Style["Yes", 14, Bold], {1.75, 1.25}]
   , Text[Style["No", 14, Bold], {0.15, 0.45}], 
   Text[Style["Yes", 14, Bold], {0.75, 0.45}]
   , Text[Style["No", 14, Bold], {1.75, 0.45}], 
   Text[Style["Yes", 14, Bold], {2.35, 0.45}]
   }
 ]
```

---

### [image]

I wish I had a better handle on automatic edge labeling. I took advantage of the `Frame->True` while placing `No` and `Yes` labels manually to the left/right respectively as per tradition. This aspect  can get tedious with larger trees.

Comment: I like your solution more than my hack :) so I deleted mine.

Comment: @Nasser, You can see the awful syntax I have used. This presentation part somehow always requires a bit of one-time-trickery.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

`Graph` allows a lot of customization: e.g.

```
elab[u_] := 
 Framed[Style[u, Red], Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 25]
vlab[u_] := Framed[u, Background -> White]
el = {Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Age<30"], vlab["Lots of Junk food"]],
     elab["Yes"]], 
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Age<30"], vlab["Exercise"]], 
    elab["No"]], 
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Lots of Junk food"], vlab["Fit"]], 
    elab["No"]], 
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Lots of Junk food"], vlab["Unfit"]], 
    elab["Yes"]], 
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Exercise"], vlab["Fit, age>30"]], 
    elab["Yes"]],
   Labeled[DirectedEdge[vlab["Exercise"], vlab["Unfit, age>30"]], 
    elab["No"]]};
g = Graph[el, VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], 
  VertexSize -> 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
layers = {{"Age > 30"}, {"Exercise", "Lot of Junk Food"}, {"Fit", "Unfit"}};

gu = GraphUnion @@ Map[PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True] &] @ Tuples[layers];

yesEdges = DirectedEdge["Age > 30", "Exercise"] | 
   DirectedEdge["Lot of Junk Food", "Unfit"] | 
   DirectedEdge["Exercise", "Fit"];

Graph[Flatten[layers], EdgeList @ gu, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> 
   (Text[Framed[Style[#2, Black], 
      RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> LightGreen], #] &), 
 EdgeLabels -> {_ -> Placed["NO", 2/3], yesEdges :> Placed["YES", 2/3]}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
   "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 2}, "Rotation" -> 3 Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = "Age > 30"["Lot of Junk Food"["Fit", "Unfit"],"Exercise"["UnFit", "Fit"]];

vLabels = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &]@Level[expr, {-1}, Heads -> True];
```

#### [`ExpressionGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionGraph.html)

```
ExpressionGraph[expr, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 EdgeLabels -> {_ -> "NO", 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 5 | 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4 | 5 \[DirectedEdge] 7 -> "YES"},
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[Style[#2 /. vLabels, Black], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
      Background -> LightGreen], #] &)]
```

[image]

```
labeledArrowhead = Arrowheads[{{.03, 1}, 
  {Automatic, .5, Graphics @
     Text[
       Framed[Style[#, 14, Black], FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White],
       {0, 0}, {0, 0}, #2]}}]&;

ExpressionGraph[expr, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 EdgeStyle -> {_ -> labeledArrowhead["NO", {-1, 0}], 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 5 | 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4 | 5 \[DirectedEdge] 7 -> 
    labeledArrowhead["YES", {1, 0}]}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[Style[#2 /. vLabels, Black], RoundingRadius -> 5, 
      Background -> LightGreen], #] &)]
```

[image]